# How to put Japanese postal code on Canadian site

Tags: international

I live in Canada and I have Japanese credit card.
Then I need to put postal card but I cannot 
How can I put Japanese postal code on Canadian site?

Comment: Sometimes 000000 will work. You may have to contact your bank, but you're probably also better off getting a Canadian account for use locally.

Comment: Because you're buying something online, and need to enter the billing address (which is in Japan)?

Comment: Ron John   Yes, I need to enter my credit card info and postal code

Comment: Might want to contact the merchant you're trying to purchase from and ask them what to do. They may not accept your card and may not ship internationally. Or, maybe their website just can't handle it and you can give the order over the phone.